# Filter the Staff name and display the staff list in frontend

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to filter only staff users and show the list of staff into the frontend where normal users can choose the staff name and input the price.

My views file for this function is quite big, so I am sharing the gist file here [Views.py](https://gist.github.com/TaufiqurRahman45/104b571873531d3d119295bb3c24b4fb)

Can anyone help me to sort out this? Thank you

model.py

```
class DailyFood(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    total = models.PositiveIntegerField()


class PurchaseHistory(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='histories')
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    balance = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    hand_cash = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

HTML

```
<form action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="modal-body">
       <div class="modal-body">
           <div class="form-group">
                <label>Total price</label>
                <input type="number" name="price" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter price">
                <label>Staff</label> <!-- #show staff list here-->
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your github link not open for me but you can filter you staff users by using `model_name__user__is_staff` and send them to your template

**solution 2:**

you can filter your users by this line of code:

```
staff = User.objects.filter(is_staff=True)
```

and send them like this to your template:

```
{% for stf in staff %}
    {{stf.username}}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope my answer is usefull ;)

Comment: dude , as I see in your views.py, you don't send staff as your context to your template . in the line you have rendered your template put `'staff':staff` in {}. and in your template you can say that `{% if not request.user.is_staff %}{%endif%}`and use the template code in this block as my second solution.
@ToufiqurRahman